# Angular check if json has been updated / different from current

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using the http service in Angular to get some json data from an online page.

For example:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});


getData() {
    return this.http.get('this url here', { headers: this.headers });
}
```

This works as it should but I don't want to update the data if it doesn't need updating.

My question is:

How do I go about checking if the json has been changed or different to my current one (who I will store in localstorage) and if it's been updated / changed, only then get the data / update it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare them like this:

```
if (localStorageJson !== currentJson) {
  update();
  storeCurrentJsonToLocal();
}
```

if it is object use JSON.stringify to get JSON from objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a service worker to check for updates read more in 
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications